# object assignment

Tags: c#

I have a scenario like:

```
MyClass obj1 = new MyClass();
............//some operations on obj1;
MyClass obj2 = new MyClass();
obj2 = obj1;
```

I have the following problem: if I modify any parameter, it is affected in both objects (as both refer to same location) - but, when I modify obj2 parameter, it should not modify that parameter value in obj1 (i.e. means both should not point to same location). How can I do that? Please help me.
I can't clone here as myclass is not implementing ICloneable and I can't modify myclass.
if I clone by serializing and deserializing, will it be a Deep clone?

Comment: What is the interface of `MyClass`?

Comment: MyClass is just implementing ISerializable..

Comment: Yes it will be a very inefficient deep clone.

Comment: actually MyClass has subobjects (as well as subsub objects too). I want to  modify sub sub object parameter in obj2 without effecting obj1. Could you Please give me any clue

Answer (score 5):

Make your `MyClass` implement [ICloneable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx) and use

```
MyClass obj1 = new MyClass();
...
MyClass obj2 = obj1.Clone();
```

If `MyClass` is not clonable, you need to look up all characteristic values in obj1 and copy them to obj2, e.g.

```
myclass obj2 = new myclass();
obj2.color = obj1.color; // .Clone();
obj2.size = obj1.size;
obj2.numberOfLimbs = obj1.numberOfLimbs;
// etc.
```

Answer (score 3):

The thing to remember with object assignment is the difference between variables and objects.

In your example, `obj1` and `obj2` are variables.  Variables can *refer* to objects, but they are not objects themselves.

What your code does is, at the end, tell both `obj1` and `obj2` to refer to the same object.

What you want to do is make a new object - which, as others pointed out, is most easily done through the `ICloneable` interface.

Answer (score 1):

Have an extension method on myClass : GetDeepCopy
Manually get make a copy of the obj and return this in GetDeepCopy.

So something like :

```
myclass obj1 = new myclass();

...

myclass obj2 = obj1.etDeepCopy();
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to KennyTM's answer, `object Clone()` method makes a copy of the invoking object. There are two type of copies which can be made. Deep copy and shallow copy. In KennyTM's answer, a deep copy is made. In a deep copy, the original object and the copied object are completely independent of each other. For more info, read up on the docs for [`ICloneable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx).

And the Clone() declaration could be something like this:

```
public object Clone()
{ 
 Myclass obj=new Myclass();
 return obj;
}
```

Comment: here MYClass is not implementing ICloneable and i cant modify the class. Is there any other alternative instead of Clone()?

Comment: @sandhya, in this case, I think a copy constructor might help.

Comment: but either way, you need access to Myclass.

Comment: @Sandhya, this might help:http://www.agiledeveloper.com/articles/cloning072002.htm

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the types on the object are simple, could you simply write a function that performs a kind of MemberwiseClone e.g.

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
// do your thing
MyClass objCopy = new MyClass();
objCopy.IamInt = obj.IamInt;
objCopy.IamString = obj.IamString;
```

Also more generally I found this [Jon Skeet](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) article very helpful when considering referencing.

Answer (score 0):

KennyTM's suggestion would be the default choice.  However, since you can't modify the source as you mentioned in a comment, you may need to write much code, possibly reflection if private members are involved.

If you can use an open-source library and if all types in the object graph of the to-be-cloned object have a default constructor, you can check out a utility in my library: [Fasterflect's DeepClone()](http://fasterflect.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Deep+Cloning).  This utility performs, no surprise, deep clone and handles cyclic references;  the implementation is backed by CIL code generation, so no performance should be much better than hand-crafted reflection code.

Answer (score 0):

If MyClass declares a copy constructor, you could do a

```
MyClass obj2=new MyClass(obj1).
```

Otherwise, you should create a function to copy as in:

```
MyClass CopyMyClassObject(MyClass obj1)
{
    MyClass Result = new MyClass();
    Result.Value1 = obj1.Value1;
    Result.Value2 = obj1.Value2;
    //...
    Result Valuen = obj1.Valuen;
    Result.Object1.Value1 = obj1.Object1.Value1;
    Result.Object1.Value2 = obj1.Object1.Value2;
    //...
    Result.Object1.Valuen = obj1.Object1.Valuen;
    //..and so on until all values have been assigned
    //The actual assignments will use whatever methods are provided in MyClass, of course.
    return Result;
}
```

After that, in your code you would simply do:

```
MyClass obj2 = CopyMyClassObject(obj1);
```

I hope this helps.