# C# Object Assignment

Tags: c#, object

I'm writing a code in C#. Please see below codes.

```
    //-- Constructor
    public frmInvoice(EditInvoice editInvoice)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        originalInfo = new EditInvoice();
        editedInfo = new EditInvoice();

        originalInfo = editInvoice;
        editedInfo = editInvoice;
        payment = new Payment();
    }

    //-- Process
    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        editedInfo.AppliedAmount = Convert.ToDouble(txtAppliedAmount.Text);
        editedInfo.PaymentCode = cboPaymentCode.SelectedValue.ToString();
        editedInfo.Remarks = txtRemarks.Text;

        if (originalInfo.AppliedAmount != editedInfo.AppliedAmount ||
            originalInfo.PaymentCode != editedInfo.PaymentCode ||
            originalInfo.Remarks != editedInfo.Remarks)
        {
            editedInfo.IsEdited = true;
        }
    }
```

Now the question is, why the original object `**originalInfo**` also changed that is supposedly not. It's annoying!

Additional: Is there a better/shortest way to compare to object (models) if have difference?

Comment: Is `editInvoice` a reference type?

Comment: No, it's not a reference type

Comment: It probably is... Isn't it a class?

Comment: You assign both `originalInfo` and `editInfo` to refer to the same object in the constructor. Obviously "changing one of them" will appear to change both, since they both refer to the same, single, object.

Comment: @Lasse but i have it assigned on different variable. so how could i do this successully?

Comment: @Bryan - Think of the variable as a giant arrow showing you the way to its datas location in memory

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486297/object-assignment

Comment: Add a new question for the additional question. There certainly are other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `editInvoice` is probably a reference type, you should clone it instead of assigning it directly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone(v=vs.110).aspx

**Update:**
since you state that editInvoice is a model, it is a reference type, any class is a reference type. A struct would be a value type for example. See this article for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx

Comment: "No, it's not a reference type".. Although I'm skeptical, its hard to tell without seeing the implementation.

Comment: editInvoice is a model. already successfully cloning it using MemberwiseClone. thanks!

Comment: @Bryan nice to see that it works, I updated my answer, so you have some more information.