# How to stop reference of other class object?

Tags: c#

I have 2 object of same class as following in c#.

```
Myclass obj1 = new Myclass();
Myclass obj2 = null;
obj2 = obj1;
obj1.Name = "abc";     //"abc" will also assign to obj2.Name.
```

When I assign `obj1.Name="abc"`, it will also assign to `obj2.Name`. I want to stop this. I have tried by const, sealed but I am not getting result.
Can anybody suggest me how to stop reference of `obj1` on `obj2`?

Comment: You must create a new instance of Myclass  of `obj2` to stop referencing from `obj1`.

Comment: Because `obj1` and `obj2` pointing the same objects. How about _not_ assign their references to each other?

Comment: [Clone it somehow.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You have two *variables*. You don't have two *objects*, only **one**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [object assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486297/object-assignment)

Comment: try [MemberwiseClone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone(v=vs.100).aspx) - also there are several SO answers on deep copy: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074381/deep-copy-of-a-c-sharp-object), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects) and this [codeproj article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38270/Deep-copy-of-objects-in-C)

Comment: Thank you.
It solved with Clone(). //obj2 = obj1.Clone();

Answer (score 4):

You want to deep clone `obj1`:

```
Myclass obj1 = new Myclass();
Myclass obj2 = DeepClone(obj1);
obj1.Name = "abc";
```

One way to deep clone an object is to Serialize it and Deserialize it back.

Here's an example using json.net:

```
public T DeepClone<T>(T instance)
{
   return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(instance));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should **clone** obj1. You can use **MemberwiseClone()**.

```
Myclass obj2 = (Myclass)obj1.MemberwiseClone();
```

Comment: No, You don't need to remove to answer. Your answer more revealing.

Comment: I think you should put a disclaimer that this method does a shallow copy, otherwise people might assume otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

see my comment above. The [msdn docs for MemberwiseClone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone(v=vs.110).aspx) cover this well.

in MyClass add the following method:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    ...
    // make a shallow copy
    public MyClass ShallowCopy()
    {
        return (MyClass) this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

then you can use `ShallowCopy()` method to create `obj2`

```
Myclass obj1 = new Myclass();
Myclass obj2 = obj1.ShallowCopy();
obj1.Name = "abc";     //"abc" won't assign to obj2.Name.
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you're seeing is because you simply have two references to a single object. It doesn't matter which reference you use to obtain the object, it's still the same object. I am assuming this is because `MyClass` is a reference type (i.e. a `class`).

Since it seems you want value type semantics here, perhaps you want `MyClass` to be a `struct`, so that a copy is created on assignment:

```
struct MyClass
{
    private string _name;
    public MyClass(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
}
```

Then your original code works as you wanted:

```
MyClass joe = new Myclass("Joe");
MyClass bob = joe;
bob.Name = "Bob";

Console.WriteLine(bob.Name); // Bob
Console.WriteLine(joe.Name); // Joe
```

See it in action here: http://ideone.com/Xwnqsa

Answer (score 0):

When you write `obj2 = obj1`, you are making obj2 point to the object that is obj1 is pointing at. You aren't creating a new separate instance that has the same value as obj1. So in order to prevent any changes that you make to obj1 appear in obj2, you need to make a deep copy of obj1, like the following:

```
obj2 = new MyClass(obj1);
obj1.Name = "abc";
```