# Linq not loading entire object

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using LINQ for quite some time now and I've never seen anything like this:
[image]

`Item.SelectedBusinessUnit` should be equal to `BusinesssUnits.First()`, but it only equals in one property.

Here the code:

```
item.BusinessUnits = BusinessUnits;
item.Units = Units;
item.SelectedBusinessUnit = BusinessUnits.First();
item.Element4CostCenter = item.CostCenters.Where(c => c.Id == item.Element4CostCenter.Id).FirstOrDefault();
item.Unit = item.Units.Where(u => u.Id == item.Unit.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Please edit your post

Comment: Please post the code you are having difficulty with (not an image). It is hard to assist in understanding the problem without an actual example of the issue.

Comment: @Sidron That doesn't really provide any useful guidance. *How* should he edit the post (and *why*)?

Comment: @Rufus L I can't see an image :/ Maybe its my browser

Comment: You need to create a [mcve]. While creating it, either you will solve it yourself, or (by posting it) allow others to solve it.

Comment: If I understood correctly, the issue is that "Name", "OrderItems" and "Orders" are null? If so, is impossible to help you without more details. Show us the  code, show us where BusinessUnits is populated.

Comment: The line where you assign `item.Unit` is actually using the current value of `item.Unit` as part of the query to find the `Unit`. So your `item.Unit` already has an `Id` property, yet you're searching for it a second time. Is that expected? It's hard to know what's going on with such a small sample of code.

Comment: Maybe worth a read
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486297/object-assignment)

Comment: Does `item.BusinessUnits.First()` equal `BusinessUnits.First()`?

Comment: @NatassiaTavares Yes, thats the problem, BusinessUnits are populated from DB using EF. On the screen you can see that it has Name and CostCenters populeted but after executing First() , those two become null.

Comment: @RufusL Yes, because BusinessUnit overrides Equals() to match Id property only, also Units where just for test because the are acting in the same strange way (not populating all properties).

Comment: I meant in the debugger, the same way you're determining that they aren't equal in your question (which, they technically ARE equal if you have overridden equals...the one property that matches is the one used by `Equals()`). I think you'll have to provide a (minimal) reproducible sample for anyone to help here. It's fairly likely that you may discover the problem yourself when you try to create a repro that's small enough for SO.

Comment: I'm afraid that won't be possible, I'm using LINQ alot and that happened first time and only in that place. There is no way I can reproduce it. I think the only way is to change approach. Thanks for trying.

Comment: *"I'm afraid that won't be possible...There is no way I can reproduce it."* - This shouldn't be difficult: your question seems to be alleging that using Linq's `First` method is creating a bad clone of your entity. So I would have thought that you just need to give the definition of your entity and a small sample of code doing `First` to demonstrate the problem. If/when you discover that this actually works fine then you will have eliminated that possibility from your problem, and can focus on what else is going on. You need to break the problem down.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some problem with lazy loading. Have you tried to evaluate result by using toList() (assuming that BusinessUnits is IEnumerable) ?